# Python pygame import 3d

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame, 3d-model

I want to ask if it is possible to import 3d-models made by Blender into pygame application-> yes, it is! I found an .obj file laoder: [link](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader)

But now my Question is, i want to make a game like Diablo 3 or WoW with a large map. Should i make a map at Blender? I did it so far, but i don't know if I can import it and use it easy then as landscape/map? Or is there any other possibilities at pygame to make landscapes/maps? Or should i use another framework and not pygame?

Thank you for the information/help about this!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: Your link doesn't work ;)

Now then, personally I wouldn't use pygame and python for something like that - I dont think it would be powerfull enough as an interpretted language for something that big - your 3D object loader is probably more for basic models and simple displays (I dont know, as I said your links broken :P )

Asking if there is a better framework is quite broad and everyone will say something different but personally I'm a fan of [Unity](http://unity3d.com). It's actually designed for C# programming but you can use Boo, which is pretty similar to python, and it will make your life so much easier in terms of rendering, physics particles... etc :)

Plus there's a terrain sculpting tool for you :)

Comment: Yes, i heard from unity, but i want stay at python and blender..is there any possibility?

Comment: I repaired the link btw